# SQL Exception error when open connection using SQL Helper Android Eclipse

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am having terrible trouble with a database connection using eclipse for an android app

I had a working example of this but since i have adapted it i have been unable to open a database connection.

I have a main activity that opens a "getData" in an Async Task

This downloads a JOSN formatted document, parses and passes to "writeSync" class

This class is designed to open the database connection add the records and then close the connection.

I am receiving an error when i run the database.open method but am unable to trap the specific error.

I have checked that i am not passing Null values and that the Helper object is populated.

Here is my code if anyone can spot my problem.

I have also written a wrapper class to pass the context when the database is opening

MAIN ACTIVITY

```
package com.example.jsondb;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public Context context;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getContext contextrequest = new getContext();

    AsyncTask<String, Void, String> JSONData;
    //Get JSON Data as a string
    //Update display#
    //SyncDataProducts();
    JSONData = new GetData().execute("null");

    String WriteDB = "";
    //pass JSONData to database to be written
    //update display

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

GETDATA

```
package com.example.jsondb;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


public String getServerData(String strURL) {    
    InputStream is = null;

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("code","A"));

    //get http data
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(strURL);
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

}catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
}


    //convert response to string
    String result = "";
    try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();

            result=sb.toString();

            //send data to database
            AsyncTask<String, Void, String> WriteData;
            WriteData = new WriteSync().execute(result);

            return result;

    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }




    return result;





}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return getServerData("http://500kgiveaway.co.uk/android/products.php");
}
}
```

WRITESYNC

```
package com.example.jsondb;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class WriteSync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
private Context adapterContext;
public String WriteSyncData(String result) {
String httpResponce = "";
String returnstring = "";
httpResponce = result;


adapterContext = getContext.getContextNow();

DataSource datasource;
datasource = new DataSource(adapterContext);

datasource.open();


try{
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(httpResponce);
        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                datasource.createProduct(json_data.getString("stockref"), json_data.getString("title"), json_data.getString("price"));

                //Get an output to the screen
                returnstring += "\n\t" + jArray.getJSONObject(i); 
        }
}catch(JSONException e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
}


return returnstring;


}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return WriteSyncData(params[0]);
}
}
```

MYSQLHELPER

```
package com.example.jsondb;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
  //Product Table
  public static final String TABLE_NAME = "products";
  public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
  public static final String COLUMN_STOCKREF = "stockref";
  public static final String COLUMN_TITLE = "title";
  public static final String COLUMN_PRICE = "price";

  private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Logma.db";
  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

  // Database creation sql statement

  private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
          + TABLE_NAME 
          + "(" + COLUMN_ID  + " integer primary key autoincrement," 
          + COLUMN_STOCKREF + " text not null,"
          + COLUMN_TITLE + " text not null,"
          + COLUMN_PRICE + " text not null"
          + ");";


  public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
      }

      @Override
      public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
      }

      @Override
      public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)     {
        Log.w(MySQLiteHelper.class.getName(),
            "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
      }

}
```

DATA SOURCE

```
package com.example.jsondb;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class DataSource {
  private SQLiteDatabase database;
  private MySQLiteHelper dbHelper;
  private String[] allColumns_products = { MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID,
            MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_STOCKREF,MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_TITLE,MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PRICE};

  public DataSource(Context context) {
       dbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(context);
      }

  public void open() throws SQLException {
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
      }

  public void close() {
        dbHelper.close();
      }

  public String createProduct(String strStockRef, String strTitle, String strPrice)   {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_STOCKREF, strStockRef);
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_TITLE, strTitle);
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PRICE, strPrice);


        long insertId = database.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME, null,
            values);

        return "Completed";
      }

}
```

GETCONTEXT

```
package com.example.jsondb;

import android.content.Context;

public class getContext extends android.app.Application {

private static getContext instance;

public getContext() {
    instance = this;
}

 public static Context getContextNow() {
    return instance;
}

}
```

Here is my stack trace

```
05-01 15:21:22.948: E/AndroidRuntime(24214): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
05-01 15:21:22.948: E/AndroidRuntime(24214): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error  occured while executing doInBackground()
05-01 15:21:22.948: E/AndroidRuntime(24214):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
05-01 15:21:22.948: E/AndroidRuntime(24214):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
05-01 15:21:22.948: E/AndroidRuntime(24214):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
05-01 15:21:22.948: E/AndroidRuntime(24214):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
05-01 15:21:22.948: E/AndroidRuntime(24214):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
05-01 15:21:22.948: E/AndroidRuntime(24214):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
05-01 15:21:22.948: E/AndroidRuntime(24214):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
05-01 15:21:22.948: E/AndroidRuntime(24214):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-01 15:21:22.948: E/AndroidRuntime(24214): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-01 15:21:22.948: E/AndroidRuntime(24214):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:236)
05-01 15:21:22.948: E/AndroidRuntime(24214):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
05-01 15:21:22.948: E/AndroidRuntime(24214):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
05-01 15:21:22.948: E/AndroidRuntime(24214):    at com.example.jsondb.DataSource.open(DataSource.java:19)
05-01 15:21:22.948: E/AndroidRuntime(24214):    at com.example.jsondb.WriteSync.WriteSyncData(WriteSync.java:24)
05-01 15:21:22.948: E/AndroidRuntime(24214):    at com.example.jsondb.WriteSync.doInBackground(WriteSync.java:51)
05-01 15:21:22.948: E/AndroidRuntime(24214):    at com.example.jsondb.WriteSync.doInBackground(WriteSync.java:1)
05-01 15:21:22.948: E/AndroidRuntime(24214):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
05-01 15:21:22.948: E/AndroidRuntime(24214):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
05-01 15:21:22.948: E/AndroidRuntime(24214):    ... 4 more
```

Comment: i have added my stock trace above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've taken a look at the source code of `ContextWrapper` (the Android framework class that is throwing the null-pointer exception), and it seems that the `Context` you are feeding to your `SQLiteOpenHelper` is `null`. The way you are requesting that `Context` (with your "getContext" class - start that with uppercase please) seems awkward to me. I usually pass the "this"-pointer to my Activity around, if no `getContext()` method is available. You will not notice this mistake until you call `getReadableDatabase()` or `getWritableDatabase()`, since the `SQLiteOpenHelper` will not use the given `Context` until then.

Aside: at the moment your code trace also calls an `AsyncTask.execute()` from a background thread (specifically, when you call `execute()` on `WriteSync` within `GetData.doInBackground()`. According to the documentation, this is not allowed. You should always call `AsyncTask.execute()` from the main thread. I know from experience that although calling execute() from another thread goes right most of the times, it surely doesn't go right ALL the time. Again: this is not related to your issue (that is just the null-Context you pass to your `SQLiteOpenHelper`), but it is something I would take a look at while you're at it.

Comment: Thankyou baske this was a great help. I have amended the getcontext so it picks uo the context from the main activity. I take on board the comments about the thread. Thabks again

Answer (score 0):

You should use the context of the Activity, BordcastReceiver or Service that is related to your Async-Task. In you case use MainActivity context:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   ...
   JSONData = new GetData(this.getContext()).execute("null");


public class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
  Context context = null
  public GetData(Context context) {
    this.context=context;
```